# C# .net 4 decimal to string consider numbers after point

Tags: c#, formatting, numbers

is there framework way to know if there are numbers after point for printing.

i want to show in textbox some decimal but if there is no numbers after the point 
the text should show int

like that:

```
txt.Text=(x - Math.Floor(x) > 0)?x.ToString("2f"):((int)x).ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
txt.Text = x.ToString("0.##");
```

This displays the decimal point only when it is necessary.

As an aside, in the code you posted you should use `x.ToString("f2")` rather than `x.ToString("2f")`.

Comment: @roy.d: Oh? I tried it, but I couldn't get it to work with 2f. See my attempt here: http://ideone.com/D1VVN